# Skspritenode texture animation doesn't work

Tags: swift, swift3, skspritenode, skaction

I just tried to animate some coins in my scene. In my other projects the animation works. But recently not here.

```
func addCoins() {

    for coins in map.coinSpawns {

        var coin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coin1")
        coin.position = coins
        coin.size = CGSize(width:map.tileSize - 10,height: map.tileSize - 10)
        let action = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(withNormalTextures: [SKTexture(imageNamed: "coin1.png"),SKTexture(imageNamed: "coin2.png"),SKTexture(imageNamed: "coin3.png"),SKTexture(imageNamed: "coin4.png")], timePerFrame: 0.5, resize: false, restore: true))

        self.addChild(coin)
        coin.run(action)
        self.coins.append(coin)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to refactor a bit your code, removing `.png` from the file name (should be the fix) and extracting the textures array outside the coin loop (optimization), so your code might be:

```
func addCoins() {
    let textures = ["coin1", "coin2", "coin3", "coin4"].flatMap { SKTexture(imageNamed: $0) }

    for coins in map.coinSpawns {
        var coin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coin1")
        coin.position = coins
        coin.size = CGSize(width:map.tileSize - 10,height: map.tileSize - 10)
        self.addChild(coin)
        self.coins.append(coin)

        let action = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: textures, timePerFrame: 0.5, resize: true, restore: false))
        coin.run(action)
    }
}
```

Comment: The real fix was that he used "SKAction.animate(withNormalTextures:". But "SKAction.animate(with:" was required. Had the same issue too. This post helped me too to figure out the problem. Thanks a lot!